# How can I make an image pop up on click? (Using Turtle module)?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

So what I'm trying to do is make a penny pop up on the screen after I click the 'start game' button.
I tried to make a boolean that was set to false, but would be set to true after the start game button was clicked.
First, here's the function to insert the penny image, and the start game button.

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
gameStart = False
wn.setup(500, 500)
wn.bgcolor('yellow')
def penny():
    penny = turtle.Turtle()
    penny.shape('circle')


def startClicked(x,y):
    if -500 < x < 500 and -500 < y < 500:
        wn.clear()
        wn.bgcolor("blue")
        gameStart = True
    else:
        gamestart = False

wn.onscreenclick(startClicked)
if gameStart:
    penny()
else:
    print("No penny")


wn.mainloop()
```

and then I made an if statement that would make the penny appear if gameStart was set to true

But when I call it in to the main code and run it, after I click the start button, the penny doesn't pop up. How do I make it so that the penny would pop up after clicking the start button?

Edit: Found the problem! All I had to do was take the if statement

```
if gameStart:
    penny()
else:
    print("No penny")
```

and put it in the function

```
def startClicked(x,y):
    if -500 < x < 500 and -500 < y < 500:
        wn.clear()
        wn.bgcolor("blue")
        gameStart = True
    else:
        gameStart = False
    if gameStart:
        penny()
    else:
        print("No penny")

wn.onscreenclick(startClicked)
wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: create minimal working code which we could run.

Comment: `register_shape` and `addshape` are two names for the same function - you can use one of them.

Comment: you have to use `global gameStart` inside `startClicked` to inform this function  that it has to assign value to external variable `gameStart` - your current code creates local variable `gameStart` inside `startClicked` and it doesn't change external/global variable `gameStart`